# Get data from multiple sql tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL database like this:

**Request**:

```
{id|user|Date|ReqType|FreqID|Status|....}
```

**ConfP**:

```
{id|Title|ConferenceName|Link|....}
```

**JournalP**:

```
{id|Title|JournalName|Link|....}
```

- `ReqID` has relationship with `id` of `ConfP` & `JournalP`
- `Status` column value is: New/Solved
- `ReqType`column value is: ConfP/JournalP

I'm using asp.net.

Each user should see his own requests in his page
and also data should select from table with name in column 'ReqType' from 'Request' table.
I want to show results on an ASP.NET page by a table in this format:

```
{Date|ReqType|Title|Link|Status}
```

MyCode is:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Request.Type, Request.OrderDate, Request.OrderTime, Request.Status, JournalP.Title 
        FROM Request 
        INNER JOIN JournalP
        ON JournalP.ID=Request.FreqID
        WHERE (Request.[UserName] = @UserName)">
```

but it just can get data from JournalP table.

at last I want to show a Status count summery like this:

```
all requests:....  | Solved:....  | New:...
```

Please help me, how should I change my codes?
Is it need additional C# code too?

Comment: First run the query direct on sql server, there see if you get data, and then if you have the correct sql command, continue to see if you have problems with the asp.net - and by the way the `FreqID` is not exist anywhere - Welcome to SO, if you ask the same question two times, you do not get better answer....

Comment: You asked this very same question not more than an hour ago.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426369/how-to-merge-two-sql-tables-in-asp-net-by-c-sharp

Comment: there was no answer in that edited post

Comment: @user3051479: Posting the same question is not the solution!! So if you don't get answer for this, are you going ask this again as a new question?  Have a look about [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: in fact I do not know how to use value of record in Type column to select a correct second tablename.

Comment: However, by looking at the result you expecting it seems that this can be obtain only by using the *Request* Table?

Comment: I do not know, please explain more

Answer (score 1):

Well try this....

Let say if you have data like below in a table called `#Temp`

```
Id  RType       RStatus
1   ConfP       New
2   ConfP       Solved
3   ConfP       New
4   JournalP    New
5   JournalP    New
5   JournalP    Solved
```

Then you can write something like

```
Select 'All request : ' + Convert(varchar,COUNT(*)) + 
    ' | Solved : ' + Convert(varchar,(select COUNT(*)
                    From #Temp
                    Where RStatus='Solved'
                    )) +
    ' | New : ' + Convert(varchar,(select COUNT(*)
                    From #Temp
                    Where RStatus='New'
                    ))
From #Temp
```

Which provide below output

***All request : 6 | Solved : 2 | New : 4***